# convert mp4 to webp without quality loss (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webp

How can I do that?

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -lossless 0 -compression_level 0 -loop 0 output_lossless0_comp0.webp
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -filter:v fps=fps=20 -lossless 0  -compression_level 3 -q:v 70 -loop 1 -preset picture -an -vsync 0 -s 800:600 output.webp
```

lead to substantial quality loss.

All other command lines i found elsewhere lead to infinite encoding times and absurd file sizes (500+ MB when the source is 3 MB).

All i need is to convert mp4 to webp without compression or quality loss.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this conversion? `webp` is an image format, `mp4` is mainly a video format.

Comment: I want to load animated background into a website, but this website only supports .gif and .webp files for animations. Sadly can't find anywhere good enough backgrounds with these filetypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `-c:v copy` option can guarantee similar size of the output with no loss in quality, but `webp` does not support `mp4` codecs so you need to use "some" encoder and any encoder will lead you to a loss in quality or much bigger size of the output file (it's a tradeoff).

If you use `libwebp` ([documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libwebp)) then you will need to experiment with the different values of its parameters to get the result that will be good for you in terms of size, quality and time.

I would start any tests with `-lossless 0` or `-lossless 1` together with a different values for `-compression_level` parameter:

> For lossy, this is a quality/speed tradeoff. Higher values give better
> quality for a given size at the cost of increased encoding time. For
> lossless, this is a size/speed tradeoff. Higher values give smaller
> size at the cost of increased encoding time. More specifically, it
> controls the number of extra algorithms and compression tools used,
> and varies the combination of these tools. This maps to the method
> option in libwebp. The valid range is 0 to 6. Default is 4.

Comment: Oh, that sounds sad. Okay, i guess i'll try to find a right compression level. Thanks!